# Decoding pickled body in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, http, aws-lambda, pickle, aws-sam

I have created a container for the following AWS Lambda function:

```py
import pickle
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

def get_embeddings_raw(texts):
    try:
        return model.encode(texts)
    except:
        print("It failed!")
        return None

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    texts = pickle.loads(event['body'])
    result = get_embeddings_raw(texts)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "result": pickle.dumps(result),
    }
```

I have deployed this container locally with `sam local start-api &` and am testing with:

```py
import requests
import pickle

texts = ['My first sentence', 'My second sentence']
my_url = "http://localhost:3000/wherewasit-embeddings/"
response = requests.post(my_url, data=pickle.dumps(texts))
print(response)
```

I get the 502 response with the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError while processing HTTP request: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte2023-09-05 14:56:31 127.0.0.1
```

Why is it trying to use `utf-8` when I use `pickle.loads`? How do I fix this?

Comment: Your `event` is a JSON-decoded event that was passed to invocation. You can't substitute it with binary data (`pickle.dumps` returns `bytes`). You may want to `base64.b64encode` the data in `request.post` and maybe wrap it with a JSON object for consistency, then `base64.b64decode` in your handler before trying to `pickle.loads`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: "Your event is a JSON-decoded event". Could you elaborate on this? Don't I send the body as `data` argument to `request.post`, which means binary data?

Comment: You do, but AWS Lambda handler cannot accept such. It needs a JSON-compatible input. You can't receive request instead of `event`, and `event` is a result of JSON-decoding of provided payoad. Lambda is **not** a webserver.